# Android: Trying to make a simple slide show app

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a slide show app, but cannot figure out how to get the pictures to display in the background. This is what I was going to do

I was going to use the background property of a  `LinearLayout`.
The problem is that the `setBackgound` takes in a resourceid,

From previous experience, you cannot have a lot of images stored as resoucrs,
so I was going to store them in the asset folder and load them in using the following code

```
try {
               String FileName=new String("background");
                AssetManager assetManager= getAssets();
               InputStream inputStream;
               inputStream=assetManager.open(FileName);  
               Bitmap Background=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);

                } catch( IOException e)
                {
```

Is there a way to load a asset into the background property?

I have used a ImageView  before, but I wanted the images to be in the background so I could draw the controls ontop of the image.  I'v seen this done in other Gallery programs.

Does anybody now a way to load pictures from assets and have them in the background with the controls on top, or another way to do this?

Comment: Thank you for helping one. I got it to work but had to use .setBackgroundDrawable instad of setbackground. Now the pictures get distorted when they are strech out to fill the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `View.setBackground(Drawable)` ( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackground(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) )
Once you have an bitmap loaded from asset, you can create `BitmapDrawable` and pass it to the method above.

As the commenter below noticed, you have to use now-deprectated `setBackgroundDrawable` to be compatible with older android versions.

Comment: Right idea but `setBackground(Drawable)` is actually exposed by `View` and not `ViewGroup`. Also that method is only available from API 16 onwards - to support older API versions `setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable)` should be used (although it is now deprecated).